# how to add a searchbar in a tableview with a parsed JSON file

Tags: swift, tableview, uisearchbar

I have successfully parsed a JSON file with the following data model into my project and my tableview.

```
import Foundation

struct ActionResult: Codable {
    let data: [Datum]
}
struct Datum: Codable {
    let goalTitle, goalDescription, goalImage: String
    let action: [Action]
}
struct Action: Codable {
    let actionID: Int
    let actionTit: String
}
```

Now I am trying to create a searchbar to search on the "actionTitle". My tableview has section headers and rows.

Relevant code:

```
var filteredData: [Action]?
    
    let searchController = UISearchController()
  
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        title = "Search"
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        filteredData = ????
        navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        parseJSON()
        
        
                func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
            filteredData = []
            if searchText == ""{
                filteredData = ????
            }
            else {
                for actions in ???? {
                if actions.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased()) {
                    filteredData.append(actions)
        }

                self.tableView.reloadData()
 }
```

I do not know what code to use where I have ????.

Thanks.

Comment: let actionTit is suppose to be actionTitle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to keep an instance of all of the available data (`allActions`), and always show your filter data (`filteredData`) in the tableView. So when there is nothing to filter, `filteredData` is equal to `allActions` (*unless you intend to hide all data when the search is empty*).

When `searchBar(_:,textDidChange:)` is called, you can use [filter(_:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter) to evaluate if the item should be included. [Apple's description](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/sequence/3018365-filter)  on the filter closure:

> A closure that takes an element of the sequence as its argument and
> returns a Boolean value indicating whether the element should be
> included in the returned array.

I don't know if there is a specific reason for declaring `filteredData: [Action]?`, is it because the data is not populated until `parseJSON()` is called? If so--I suggest initializing an empty arrays and populating them when the data is available.

Also, does `parseData()` produce an instance of `Datum`? I believe this piece of your code is not included, so I am adding `datum: Datum?`.
If I am wrong, please provide more info what `parseJSON()` populates and I will update my answer.

```
var result: ActionResult? {
    didSet {
        guard let result = result else { return }
        allSectionDataActionMap = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: result.data.enumerated().map { ($0.0, ($0.1, $0.1.actions)) })
        updateFilteredData()
    }
}


var allSectionDataActionMap = [Int: (datum: Datum, actions: [Action])]()

// Maps the section index to the Datum & filtered [Action]
var filteredSectionDataActions = [Int: (datum: Datum, actions: [Action])]()

let searchController = UISearchController()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    title = "Search"
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    navigationItem.searchController = searchController

    // ...
    parseJSON()
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return filteredSectionDataActions.count
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredSectionDataActions[section]?.actions.count ?? 0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") ?? UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
    if let action = filteredSectionDataActions[indexPath.section]?.actions[indexPath.row] {
        // setup cell for action
        cell.textLabel?.text = action.actionTitle
    }
    return cell
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    updateFilteredData(for: searchText.lowercased())
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func updateFilteredData(for searchText: String = String()) {

    if searchText.isEmpty {

        filteredSectionDataActions = allSectionDataActionMap

    } else {

        for (index, (datum, actions)) in allSectionDataActionMap {

            let filteredActions = actions.filter { $0.actionTitle.lowercased().contains(searchText) }

            if filteredActions.isEmpty {

                filteredSectionDataActions[index] = (datum, actions)

            } else {

                filteredSectionDataActions[index] = (datum, filteredActions)

            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I have used the code and it runs without any errors, but it is not filtering any data. I replaced title with actionTitle, because that is the data i would like to filter on. In my "numbersOfRowsInSection" i have the following code: if let result = result { return result.data[section].action.count. Also in my "cellForRowAt" i have let action = result?.data[indexPath.section].action[indexPath.row. Do I need to use filterData here? I tried to replace action by filteredData but that gives me an error.

Comment: Ahh I think understand more now what you're doing on your end. There are a couple of things wrong with the code I posted, which I can update. What you're doing is using the Datum as a section and the actions as the rows. Two simple fixes would be 1.Add properties/methods to Datum so that each Datum can filter it's actions, or 2. make filteredData: [Datum: [Actions]] and use that for your tableView data. I will post the Dictionary option, if you want other suggestions let me know.

Comment: Also, those 2 suggestions are not "the best" approaches. Longterm, I would suggest making your objects into objc classes with objc properties so you can use an NSPredicate for filtering

Comment: Unless you are only using 1 section in the table view and showing all Actions in that single section.. So to actually get a proper answer, how are you setting up your tableView/what is your goal for displaying sections/rows?

Comment: I am trying to create an overview of 2,000 actions in 10 sections, which can be filtered by name actionTitle. These are 2,000 sustainability actions people can do. If I type for instance "install low flow showered" only the action with this text should appear. Should I leave out the sections?

Comment: Leaving out the sections depends on how you want your tableView to look visually to the user. You accepted the answer so I assume something work. If you have anymore questions with this or other iOS stuff you can send me a message on twitter (@notMoni), I think there's a more efficient way to handle your data and I'm happy to help out.

Comment: I will reach out via twitter. The solution works partially, it only searches the first section